# Viterbi Decoder without traceback

Tags: digital-communications, forward-error-correction, viterbi-algorithm

How can I use Viterbi algorithm for a real time scenario where I cannot afford to have delay in the tracing back the best path to the initial state?

Comment: Too many questions in one question. Ask one, spare the others for separate later questions. The question indicates you haven't yet fully understood what Viterbi does (which is OK), but you start making up connections to other things (which is not OK, because it makes little sense for us to say "no, this is impossible, or wrong, did you make that up?"). So please, select the most basic of the multiple questions you're asking, and remove the others. We can build up on the answer later on. And: give yourself more time to understand the textbook you're probably reading. This is hard stuff!

Comment: Done! How can I decode without having to traceback the best path?

Comment: Why not use an on-line viterbi decoder? 
http://www.dcs.fmph.uniba.sk/diplomovky/obhajene/getfile.php/main.pdf?id=143&fid=289&type=application%2Fpdf

Comment: There will always be some delay involved with decoding an error-correcting code. At a high level, they work by adding redundant information that is spread across multiple transmitted symbols. In order to make an optimal decision on the values of the underlying information symbols, you need to observe at least some those extra, redundancy-carrying symbols. This adds latency because you need to wait for all of them to arrive. It isn't clear whether the online Viterbi decoder linked above is intended to reduce latency at all; its main claim is that it in some cases *can* require less memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A register exchange method implementation of Viterbi decoder avoids trace back and a nominal initial delay (one time delay or boot up delay) is unavoidable. But this method requires more memory resources.